# ruby multiline scan between ; and negate?

Tags: ruby, regex, linux

I'm trying to match text between `;-`.

I used:

```
  inputx.scan(/;-.+?\n[^\n]*;-/)
```

but it doesn't work.

My text is:

```
 baseball;-1
    norm;4
   dad;3
   soda;1
  robot;-8
   mmm;3
      fly;-1
    cat;4
    bird;4
   dragon;6
  mor;-1
```

I need to separate the text between `;-`.

For example, this is the first element of the resulting array:

```
 baseball;-1
    norm;4
   dad;3
   soda;1
  robot;-8
```

And this is second:

```
     fly;-1
    cat;4
    bird;4
   dragon;6
  mor;-1
```

Comment: Have your tried using `split`?

Comment: not but How I could split between lines (multiline)?

Comment: ``inputx.split("\n").map{|s| s.split(/;-?/)}``?

Comment: Try [`s.scan(/.*-\d+$(?m:.*?-\d+$)/)`](http://rubular.com/r/7oM30qKSXF)

Comment: not get all text between lines

Comment: yes works wiktor

Comment: I posted the answer with explanation below.

Comment: Where are you getting this text? It's not a standard format at all. Why is `robot;-8
   mmm;3` not the second element? When asking you need explain all the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a regex that will match any line that ends with `-` and 1 or more digits, and then matches any text up to the first line that ends with `-` and 1 or more digits:

```
/.*-\d+$(?m:.*?-\d+$)/
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/7oM30qKSXF)

**Details**:

- `.*-\d+$` - any 0+ chars other than line breaks, followed with `-` and 1+ digits
- `(?m:.*?-\d+$)` - a modifier group  where `.` matches line breaks matching:

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
  - `$` - end of line.

Comment: That's very interesting. I learned two things from your answer: how the fact that `.*` does not match newlines can be used to advantage, and `(?m: ... )` which I not seen before. As I understand `?m:` simply means that `.` matches everything, including newlines, within the group. Is that correct?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: correct. You may read more about this syntax at [*Combining Non-Capture Group with Inline Modifiers*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#modifiers) section at rexegg.com.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) twice, the first to split by lines, and the second to split based on the presence of either `;` or `;-` (using the pattern `/;-?/`)

The pattern `/;-?/` matches a semicolon followed by an optional `-`.

```
inputx.split("\n").map{|s| s.split(/;-?/)}
#=> [[" baseball", "1"], ["    norm", "4"], ["   dad", "3"], ["   soda", "1"], ["  robot", "8"], ["   mmm", "3"], ["      fly", "1"], ["    cat", "4"], ["    bird", "4"], ["   dragon", "6"], ["  mor", "1"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

A pattern with `scan` or `split` results in a regex that is needlessly complicated because it's not the best tool in the box for the problem.

I'd use something like this:

```
text = <<EOT
baseball;-1
    norm;4
  dad;3
  soda;1
  robot;-8
  mmm;3
      fly;-1
    cat;4
    bird;4
  dragon;6
  mor;-1
EOT

ary = [[]]
text.lines.each do |l|
  if l[';-'] ... l[';-']
    ary.last << l
  else
    ary << []
  end
end

ary
# => [[" baseball;-1\n",
#      "    norm;4\n",
#      "   dad;3\n",
#      "   soda;1\n",
#      "  robot;-8\n"],
#     ["      fly;-1\n",
#      "    cat;4\n",
#      "    bird;4\n",
#      "   dragon;6\n",
#      "  mor;-1\n"]]
```

If you don't want trailing new-lines:

```
ary = [[]]
text.lines.map(&:chomp).each do |l|
  if l[';-'] ... l[';-']
    ary.last << l
  else
    ary << []
  end
end
ary
# => [[" baseball;-1", "    norm;4", "   dad;3", "   soda;1", "  robot;-8"],
#     ["      fly;-1", "    cat;4", "    bird;4", "   dragon;6", "  mor;-1"]]
```

If you don't want the whitespace surrounding each element:

```
ary = [[]]
text.lines.map(&:strip).each do |l|
  if l[';-'] ... l[';-']
    ary.last << l
  else
    ary << []
  end
end
ary
# => [["baseball;-1", "norm;4", "dad;3", "soda;1", "robot;-8"],
#     ["fly;-1", "cat;4", "bird;4", "dragon;6", "mor;-1"]]
```

How does this work? The `..` and `...` operator changes meaning depending on whether it's used in the context of a Range, or in an `if` condition. `..` is called a "flip-flop" operator, which changes state when the first condition is met. It will begin returning `true` at that point, and will continue to do so until the second condition is met, at which point it begins returning false again. That makes it easy to look for something, then begin acting on subsequent lines until the second condition occurs.

Normally we'd use different conditions, such as searching for "begin" and "end" in a block of lines in a file. In this case though, we needed it to not immediately toggle since both the start and end condition were the same, which is where `...` comes it. It waits one loop before testing for the second condition, allowing this code to continue, find the next lines until the "closing" `';-'`.
I have to say, this data set is one of the weirdest I've ever seen. (The weirdest was some binary data for the address book out of an old email program years ago). I'd be concerned about the process that's generating it, and if that generation was under my control I'd change it to use something more standard.

Comment: I've read that Matz may one day (not v2x) do away with the flip-flop operator. I hope not, as I continue to find new uses for it.

Comment: I read the articles, and the workaround for it is even less readable than the current version. The issue is that people don't read the documentation for a language any more, most don't even look at a book about the language, so they miss much of the functionality out of the gate, then run into features and assume they're worthless because they've never used them, and, maybe in their world they would be because they'd rather write a lot of code to do the same thing. flip-flop is amazingly useful for parsing all sorts of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) and Ruby's [flip-flop operator](https://blog.newrelic.com/2015/02/24/weird-ruby-part-3-fun-flip-flop-phenom/). This does not require the use of a regular expression. `str` is the string given by the OP.

```
arr = str.lines.chunk do |line|
  true if line.include?('-') ... line.include?('-')
end.select(&:first).map { |_,a| a.join }
  #=> ["baseball;-1\nnorm;4\ndad;3\nsoda;1\nrobot;-8\n", 
  #    "fly;-1\ncat;4\nbird;4\ndragon;6\nmor;-1\n"] 

arr.each { |s| puts "\n"; puts s }
baseball;-1
norm;4
dad;3
soda;1
robot;-8

fly;-1
cat;4
bird;4
dragon;6
mor;-1
```

It is necessary to use three (not two) dots in the flip-flop expression (search for "three dot" in the reference given above).

Comment: I just noticed that @theTinMan's earlier answer also used the Flip-Flop operator.